# Can't remove PHPMyAdmin. Ubuntu 18.04. Usual not working

Tags: apt, 18.04, phpmyadmin, php7

I found that PHPMyAdmin no longer is working after I upgraded to 18.04 due to the fact that `php-mcrypt` is deprecated. I was getting an error about that package. I decided to remove phpmyadmin and try installing it fresh.

Here are my attempts:

```
balter@spectre:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
balter@spectre:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'phpmyadmin' for glob 'phpmyadmin*'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-sphinxdoc php-bz2 php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php7.2-bz2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 25.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 84795 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 installed phpmyadmin package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed phpmyadmin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
balter@spectre:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-sphinxdoc php-bz2 php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php7.2-bz2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 25.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 84795 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 installed phpmyadmin package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed phpmyadmin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

### Attempt 1:

```
balter@spectre:/var/cache/debconf$ sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
balter@spectre:/var/cache/debconf$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: phpmyadmin is broken or not fully installed
balter@spectre:/var/cache/debconf$ sudo apt purge phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-sphinxdoc php-bz2 php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php7.2-bz2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 25.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 84795 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
Determining localhost credentials from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf: succeeded.
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 installed phpmyadmin package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed phpmyadmin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
balter@spectre:/var/cache/debconf$ sudo apt remove phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-sphinxdoc php-bz2 php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php7.2-bz2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 25.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 84795 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
Determining localhost credentials from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf: succeeded.
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 installed phpmyadmin package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed phpmyadmin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

### Attempt 2

```
balter@spectre:/var/cache/debconf$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for balter:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up phpmyadmin (4:4.6.6-5) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
Replacing config file /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf with new version
Replacing config file /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php with new version
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
 installed phpmyadmin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looked at this error

> debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by
>   another process: Resource temporarily unavailable

You need to solve this  before re-install `phpmyadmin`.

Run this command to clear it.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
```

**Edit**

Based on attempt 2 error

> dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):  installed
>   phpmyadmin package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit
>   status 10

We can remove the dpkg files manually by running below code:

```
rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.*
```

More details can be found on [Trying to uninstall phpmyadmin "dpkg: error while cleaning up:"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/trying-to-uninstall-phpmyadmin-dpkg-error-while-cleaning-up)

Comment: See "Attempt 1" in original post.

Comment: did you run `sudo apt autoremove` ?

Comment: See "Attempt 2" :)

Comment: `rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.*`

Comment: Bingo! Please update answer so I can accept.

Comment: answer edited..